# AWK command reduce YYYYMMDD by 4 years

Tags: awk, sed

I am a csv file with 2 columns, i.e. DATE and TYPE. If Type is B, the DATE should reduce by 4 years i.e. in YYYYMMDD YYYY should be -4. Example if the date is 20200422, the date should become 20160422 for data B under TYPE.

Thank you!

DATE,TYPE,

20200101,A

20200422,B

20200401,B

Comment: Good thing it's 4 years, right? So if YYYY0229 is valid, it maps to a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

Since in Awk, a string that looks like a number can be treated like one, the solution can be a simple as subtracting 40000.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print 20200422 - 40000 }'
20160422

$ awk 'BEGIN { print "20200422" - 40000 }'
20160422
```

Comment: Hi @Kaz, So how would I run this command for a comma delimited file (test.csv) which has many dates and types. So for only type i.e. B the date should be reduced by 4 years. The DATES could be different for different TYPEs of B.

Comment: I have added a sample file in the question.

Comment: awk -F, 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} NR==1 {$3="New_DATE"} $2 ~ /B/ {$3=$1-40000} {print}' test_date.csv > outputfile.csv

Answer (score 0):

Just learned the `e` flag (for "execute") a few days ago. It seems to work great for this problem. Note that this is a GNU extension - this trick may not work, perhaps, on MacOS (which is based on FreeBSD).

Here's the input file I created for testing:

```
$ cat myfile.csv
DATE,TYPE
20200310,B
20180228,B
20181215,A
20130404,A
20050228,B
```

And here is the `sed` solution and the output:

```
$ cat myfile.csv | sed -E 's/^([[:digit:]]{8}),B$/echo $((\1 - 40000)),B/e'
DATE,TYPE
20160310,B
20140228,B
20181215,A
20130404,A
20010228,B
```

Of course, the "date" won't be a valid date if you start, for example, with 19040229 and subtract 4 from the year; 1904 was a leap year, but 1900 was not. Luckily, 2000 is divisible by 400, so it was a leap year; you will be fine for years between 1905 and 2103.

A safer option would be to replace `echo $((\1 - 40000)),B` with

```
date -d "& -4 years" +%Y%m%d,B
```